# Password validation with javascript AND cancel form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use javascript to make sure users that register on my site do not have symbols and have a minimum of 8 characters in their password. I have an onclick function assigned to the input btn and it doesnt seem to be working.

Here is the JS Fiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/fh8o5vub/

How exactly does the password syntax check work? I dont understand the formatting..

Also, how do I stop php form submission? Return false isnt doing it..

```js
function CheckPassword() {
    var passw = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,14}$/;
    if (document.getElementById("password".value.match(passw)) {
        return true;
      } else {
        alert('You can only use standard letters a-z and your psasword must be atleast eight letters!')
        return false;
      }
    }
```

```html
<form onsubmit="CheckPassword(password)" id="step2form" name="step2form" method="post" autocomplete="off" action="#">

  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control formsubfree" ng-model="formData.password" required>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block formsubfree" id="b" style="font-family: 'klavikaRegular'; letter-spacing: 1px;" name="skip" value="0">CONTINUE</button>

</form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: This [website](http://regex101.com/r/kP7iY4/1) is a good resource for decoding a regex.

Comment: Hi you already got solution ,before asking question??

Comment: I think you need a return in the onsubmit.

Comment: Here is an updated jsFiddle that moves the JavaScript to the head
http://jsfiddle.net/fh8o5vub/5/

Comment: As @MrLister said `onsubmit="return CheckPassword(password)"`

Comment: This does not work on my website :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the regex works but for the form not to submit, you need
`onsubmit="return CheckPassword(password)"` then in the function `document.getElementById("password").value.match(passw)` because your mixing in a the `.match` function into the `.getElementById` function so it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, you need to use `onsubmit="return CheckPassword(password)"` however, I would dare say that you actually have an error, because `password` from what I can see is not defined.

Furthermore, since you don't take a variable in in your method definition (`function CheckPassword()`) you shouldn't be sending anything to it. That won't cause it to not be called, but still unnecessary.